# Is there any benefit to attacking enemies from different angles?

Tags: might-and-magic-heroes-6

Given enough movement points to adjust the position of my units, I can attack my enemies from different angles. It looks like each enemy unit just turns to face me anyway, so is there really any point in positioning my troops to attack from different angles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, angle itself doesn't make any difference in terms of damage.  Most creatures can only retaliate once per turn though, so there is an advantage to attacking it with multiple creatures during the same turn.  It will retaliate against the first attacker, but the rest will be able to do their damage without getting hit back.

Keep in mind that positioning can have other advantages as well.  Maybe it puts you close enough to attack a different creature next turn, or blocks an enemy's path (especially useful against large creatures).  Or maybe it puts you adjacent to a ranged creature, thus preventing it from using its ranged attack.

Answer (score 2):

Not directly, but some creatures (like the The [Sun Crusader](http://guides.gamepressure.com/mightandmagicheroesvi/guide.asp?ID=12879)) or skills (I think Charge or something) give you a damage bonus per travelled square.